# Is "Real Analysis with Economic Applications", by Efe A. Ok, a good book for a self-teaching beginner in real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation, economics

I'm interested in self teaching myself Real Analysis with the primary purpose of using it for economics, for this I decided to use [*Real analysis with economic applications*](https://books.google.de/books/about/Real_Analysis_with_Economic_Applications.html?id=pYJmnnnA1dkC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Efe A. Ok

Now what I was wondering was if this was a good book for somebody without a Maths background to use to self study a thing, as I'm primary interested in it for the methods used in economic theory.

Am I making a mistake reading this now or do I need more background in Maths to read this particular book? As I'm not finding it the most easy thing to read and I'm not sure if I'm understanding everything in it correctly, 50 pages in and I've already got quite a headache! Which sucks.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149794/which-book-should-i-use-to-learn-analysis?rq=1

Comment: [Real Analysis an Applied Subject](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931928/is-real-analysis-an-applied-subject?rq=1)

Comment: [Real analysis for a non-mathematician](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316640/real-analysis-for-a-non-mathematician?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

$(1)$ Analysis I [Terence Tao](https://www.amazon.in/Analysis-v-1-Terence-Tao/dp/8185931623)

$(2)$ [A Basic Course in Real Analysis (Ajit Kumar and S. Kumaresan)](https://www.amazon.in/Basic-Course-Real-Analysis/dp/148221637X)

Let me know if you need soft-copies of these books.